# Show $\langle \mathbf r\mathbf r^T\rangle=\tfrac 1 3\langle r^2\rangle $ for isotropically distributed vectors.

Tags: expected-value, tensors, symmetry

In my reader it is stated that $\langle \mathbf r\mathbf r^T\rangle=\tfrac 1 3\langle r^2\rangle $ for isotropic vectors $\mathbf r$ but with no further explanation and I'd like to know where it comes from. Here $\langle \ \rangle $ denotes an expectation value, $\mathbf r\in\mathbb R^3$ is a position vector and  is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix.

My first guess would be to split the tensor in an spherically symmetric part and a non-symmetric traceless part:
\begin{align}
\mathbf r\mathbf r^T &=\tfrac 1 3\text{tr}(\mathbf r\mathbf r^T )+\big(\mathbf r\mathbf r^T-\tfrac 1 3\text{tr}(\mathbf r\mathbf r^T )\big) \\
&=\underbrace{\tfrac 1 3(\mathbf r\cdot\mathbf r)}_{\text{spher. symmetric}}+\underbrace{\big(\mathbf r\mathbf r^T-\tfrac 1 3(\mathbf r\cdot\mathbf r)\big)}_{\text{non-sym. traceless}}
\end{align}
My second guess would be that taking the expectation value removes the non-symmetric part but I have trouble showing this. Also I don't understand why the non-symmetric part has to be traceless so in turn I dont understand see where the prefactor $\tfrac 1 3\langle r^2 \rangle$ comes from. I could have also picked a more general split $a+(\mathbf r\mathbf r^T-a)$. Any help?

Comment: The only isotropic rank-2 Cartesian tensors are (scalar) multiples of identity.

Comment: @A What exactly is your definition of an "isotropically distributed vector"?

Comment: @A Regarding you question about the trace: note that
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(AB) = \operatorname{Tr}(BA)
$$
holds for all matrices $A,B$. Consequently,
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf r\mathbf r^T) = \operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf r^T \mathbf r) = \operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf r^2) = \mathbf r^2.
$$
For the second term in the traceless part, note that
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(c ) = c \cdot \operatorname{Tr} () = 3c.
$$

Comment: @user10354138 So that would be the spherically symmetric part. Would the following reasoning be correct: if I take a rotationally symmetric expectation value of a tensor only the isotropic survives so it is proportional to the identity tensor?

Comment: @BenGrossmann There was no definition in the reader but I guess if the expectation value is computed using some probability distribution $\langle T\rangle=\int d\mathbf rT(\mathbf r)f(\mathbf r)$ then isotropy would mean that $f$ is radially symmetric i.e. $f(\mathbf r)=f(r)$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I understand the trace identities you mention but I'm still puzzled why the expectation value kills the non-symmetric traceless part. I could have also picked the split $a+(\mathbf r\mathbf r^T-a)$ and if the expectation just kills the non-symmetric part the answer would be $\langle \mathbf r\mathbf r^T\rangle=a $. So why does it kill the non-symmetric _traceless_ part specifically?

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion I'm not sure I understand your question. Here's something that might help: the trace is a linear function, which means that the expectation of the trace is equal to the trace of the expectation. Thus, if something is "killed" by expectation (i.e. has expectation equal to the zero matrix), then the trace of that expectation is zero which means that the expected value of the trace must be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to the first question: let $A = \langle \mathbf r\mathbf r^T \rangle$; note that $A$ is necessarily symmetric. We note that for any unit vector $\mathbf v$, we have
$$
\langle (\mathbf r ^T \mathbf v)^2 \rangle = \langle \mathbf v^T \mathbf r \mathbf 
 r^T \mathbf v\rangle = \mathbf v^T \langle \mathbf r \mathbf r^T \rangle \mathbf v = \mathbf v^T A\mathbf v.
$$
Now, because $\mathbf r$ is isotropically distributed, $\mathbf v^TA\mathbf v$ must be equal to some constant $c$ for all unit-vectors $\mathbf v$. Now, for a symmetric matrix $M$: if $\mathbf v^T M \mathbf v = 0$ holds for all unit vectors $\mathbf v$, then it must hold that $M = 0 $. Thus, we may conclude that $A - c I = 0$ (where $I$ denotes the identity matrix). Thus, $A = cI$.

Now, note that
$$
\operatorname{Tr}\langle \mathbf r \mathbf r^T \rangle = \langle r^2\rangle  = \operatorname{Tr}(c I) = 3c \implies c = \frac 13 \langle r^2 \rangle.
$$

Comment: Thanks this was what I was looking for!